# Error in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal

This is a small code of paypal controller i cakephp

its working fine in my localhost but its give me error in live

if you need more information then write in comment

undefine index username

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: username [APP/Controller/PaymentsController.php]
public function _initPaypal() {
    $config = $this->User->findByUsername('admin');
    $config = $config['Username'];
    App::import('Vendor', 'Paypal/paypal');
    $this->paypal = new Paypal($config['paypal_api_username'],        $config['paypal_api_password'], $config['paypal_signature']);
}
```

its give me error like

notice(8) undefine index user name 
in localhost
its working fine

thanks

Answer (score 2):

[CakePHP's magic `findBy` methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#magic-find-types) return in the same format as `find('first')` so your `$config` result will be indexed by the model's alias, not the field you've searched with. Therefore, `$config['Username']` should be `$config['User']`.  So your controller action should look like:-

```
public function _initPaypal() {
    $user = $this->User->findByUsername('admin');
    $config = $user['User'];
    App::import('Vendor', 'Paypal/paypal');
    $this->paypal = new Paypal($config['paypal_api_username'], $config['paypal_api_password'], $config['paypal_signature']);
}
```

I've modified your variable names a little to make the difference between the query result (`$user`) and `$config` (at first read this confused me).

I don't see why your example code would have worked anywhere without the correct alias index.

If this doesn't fix your problem check what `$this->User->findByUsername('admin')` is returning using either `debug()` or `print_r()` and make sure it is generating the expected SQL query (and that that works on your server).

Comment: now its give me this error Notice (8): Undefined index: User [APP/Controller/PaymentsController.php, line 123]

Comment: @sagarparmar what do you see if you print out `$user` as suggested in my answer? *E.g.* `print_r($user);`. I suspect your database isn't returning any result and therefore `$user` is returning an empty array. Check what is returned and then the query generated as I suggested. Perhaps `admin` does not exist in your database on the server.

Comment: @SagarParmar if it is return `array()` then your problem is mostly with the database. Make sure that there is a record for `username = 'admin'` in your `users` table. If that exists check the SQL being generated by Cake and that it runs as expected on your database.

Comment: @SagarParmar great! Glad to have helped. Please accept my answer so that others with a similar problem can find the solution easily. :-)